# Using OAuth2 by thephpleague in PHP/Slim

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, slim

I would like to have an authorization added to my project.

I found this library on the internet:
[thephpleague/oauth2](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/). However, after reading it's documentation I can't realize how to implement it in my project. I just want to have a basic authorization, but I struggle with implementing this library in my project. I don't know from where to start from.

Also, I'm a beginner in PHP/Slim ( and now trying to learn about authorization ) and any step-by-step guide or any other help would be nice.

Comment: This question is unfortunately a bit too unfocused and off-topic. This site is for when you run into some specific issue with your implementation of some code. Then you can come here, post your attempt, explain where you're stuck, give us some example data, expected result and what currently happens. And asking for a complete guides/tutorials are off-topic here.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I totally agree with you. Unfortunately I didn't know where and who to ask, that's why I posted this question here. If you would like to redirect me somewhere or suggest anything I will appreciate it.

Comment: I honestly don't know of any specific place for these types of questions. You need to do some research...

Comment: You may ask such question in the Slim forum or in the Slim slack channel.